# I need to collapse table one row at a time .. i have used material (React JS) Collapsible table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a dynamic table where the data is coming from an API.

Clicking the *down arrow* icon, those specific data are getting fetched and displayed depending on the **Table Names** as a table data.

The problem is when user clicks on one row and after that if the user clicks on another row at the same time one Table data has to be shown or one row needs to get expanded at a time.

E.g., if i click the second row, other rows needs to be closed and only the second row table data must be visible.

**Row Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';

const useRowStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      borderBottom: 'unset',
    },
  },
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
  return {
    name,
    calories,
    fat,
    carbs,
    protein,
    price,
    history: [
      { date: '2020-01-05', customerId: '11091700', amount: 3 },
      { date: '2020-01-02', customerId: 'Anonymous', amount: 1 },
    ],
  };
}

function Row(props) {
  const { row } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useRowStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableRow className={classes.root}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box margin={1}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                History
              </Typography>
              <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                    <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {historyRow.date}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      }),
    ).isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5),
];
```

**CollapsibleTable Component:**

```
export default function CollapsibleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add an open and onClick property to row that is populated by your table. example:

```
function Row(props: any) {
    const { row } = props;
    const classes = useRowStyles();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TableRow className={classes.root}>
                <TableCell>
                    <IconButton aria-label="expand row" size="small" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.open ? "" : row.name)}>
                        {props.open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
                    <Collapse in={props.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <Box margin={1}>
                            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                                History
                            </Typography>
                            <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                                <TableHead>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                    {row.history.map((historyRow: any) => (
                                        <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {historyRow.date}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">
                                                {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </Box>
                    </Collapse>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

your table looks like this:

```
export default function CollapsibleTable() {
            const [openRow, setOpenRow] = useState("")
            return (
                <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                    <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
                        <TableBody>
                            {rows.map((row) => (
                                <Row key={row.name} row={row} open={row.name == openRow} onClick={(name) => setOpenRow(name)} />
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            );
        }
```

Comment: Yes thankyou for your comment @Mathieu it worked but also at the same time that  row needs to be get closed like clicking on the second row only the second row data will be shown and if the user clicks on that same row the collapse needs to be. Toggled like the second row will get closed again

Comment: I made an error in the collapsable table and updated the onclick function.
The toggle should work.

Comment: Thankyou Mathieu